# How to install SFTP plugin in Sublime Text 3 on Windows 7 64bit

Tags: sublimetext3

I cannot install ST3's SFTP plugin on Windows 7 64bit. It is installed but all its menus are greyed out, not active.

I read support. It says:

> To fix this, please perform the following:
>
> Open Preferences > Browse Packages… Navigate into the SFTP/ folder and
>
> open SFTP.py in Sublime.

I open `Browse Packages...`  as written but there is no `SFTP/` folder in `Sublime Text 3\Packages` folder thet is opened. Neither in `Sublime Text 3\Packages` nor in `Sublime Text 3\Packages\User`. I only have two folders there:

```
\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Package Control
\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User
```

What do I do wrong? How may install or set the plugin correctly? On my computer the mentioned directory located here `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\`. May ST3 install plugin to some other directories?

Comment: I think this is better suited for superuser.com

Comment: it works fine in my windows 8 64 bit, I install sftp from package control, try check this link http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp/installation

Answer (score 4):

Only testing version of the SFTP plugin works in Sublime Text 3.

How To :

1. Run "Package Control: Add Repository" command
2. Paste "http://sublime.wbond.net/testing/packages.json" (official repo)
3. Install or upgrade SFTP plugin from the Package Control

Done ;)

Answer (score 3):

SFTP doesn't work in Sublime Text 3. At least on Windows 7 64 bit. But it works fine in Sublime Text 2. So I uninstalled ST3, installed ST2 and installed SFTP plugin. And am quite happy.

Answer (score 1):

Had troubles finding the folder... Turned out it was located at c:\Users\PROFILENAME\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\

Though I can't get the package to work properly ><

Answer (score 0):

From Package Control (`Cntrl + Shift + p` as shortcut) you can do:

- Search for `Package Control: Install Package`
- Search `SFTP` and install it

And you will have your SFTP plugin installed correctly, without having to add any repositories.